# Mocking data sequences through InputStream and OutputStream

Tags: java, mocking, inputstream, outputstream

I've designed Java class that implements some server protocol. For example, it has `getProtocolVersion()` method, which return latest protocol version. Object of this class is connected to the server through `InputStream` and `OutputStream` implementations.

I have a test with stubs for each server command. Every test creates `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` with expected client requests and server responses so I can perform logic unit testing of my protocol implementation with JUnit. It's works but creating fixture (prepare data) for each command test is too boring.

Is it really to use mocking in my case? Is this solution less complex? How to mock data sequences through input and output streams?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it really to use mocking in my case?" Is it really *what*?

Comment: Is the sequences text based. `new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());`

Comment: Peter, my sequences contain raw bytes and UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: Jon, I mean how to mock InputStream and OutputStream implementations (data sequences through these streams).

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `Streams` in an object that is easier to create and assert with.  This can serve for end-to-end tests.

For unit tests, you can extract the logic into methods that are independently testable without having to setup a complex fixture.